# c# определить нажатие клавиши в консольном проекте

Tags: c#

мне нужно определить нажатие клавиш в консольном проекте (не набора в консоли) не блокируя работу приложения

как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Перечислите и опишите подробнее события, которые вам нужно отловить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хочешь сделать кейлоггер? Аяяй. По попе за такое нужно бить.

Но в целом ответ следующий: нужно использовать WinApi для этого и отлавливать ивенты самой операционной системы. Эта статья поможет: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/

Но проще будет наработки чужие использовать. Например, даный проект делает именно то, что тебе нужно, используя более чем простой синтаксис: https://github.com/fabriciorissetto/KeystrokeAPI. Долго разбиратся не придется.

Comment: сейчас бы кейлоггеры делать на с# в 2017 году

Answer (score 4):

Самый банальный способ определения нажатия клавиш для случая, когда Ваше приложение не является фоновым и активно:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(key.Key + " клавиша была нажата");
        }
        while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape); // по нажатию на Escape завершаем цикл
    }
}
```

Если же нужен способ отслеживания нажатия клавиш, когда приложение не активно и является фоновым процессом, то нам нужно импортировать методы вспомогательной библиотеки `user32.dll`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
```

Есть хороший ответ, касаемо этого варианта: [Capture a keyboard keypress in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413314/5275890). В принципе, если воспользоваться поиском, то ответы можно найти.
Или вот готовый хороший и полноценный ответ: [Background Key Press Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852519/5275890)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

вот ето может помочь, по крайней мере отсюда я брал код для отслеживания перемещения указателя мыши вне формы приложения.